# What instantiates a CacheBackendInterface?

Tags: 8

I am working on upgrading a module and there is a use statement

```
use Drupal\Core\Cache\CacheBackendInterface;
```

What is the point of using an interface like that?  Interfaces dont have actual code and this .module file doesnt inherit  from that interface.

Now when the module is in enabled i get

```
Error: Cannot instantiate interface Drupal\Core\Cache\CacheBackendInterface in /srv/www/mydev/current/core/lib/Drupal/Component/DependencyInjection/Container.php, line 265
```

and the only lines I can find relating to the cache interface are

```
\Drupal::cache('libraries')->deleteAll();
\Drupal::cache('libraries')->set($name, $library);
```

So I am confused as to why this is supposed to clear the cache?

Or is it that it is not supposed work and the latest version of the module is not complete yet?

Answer (score 1):

You're using an old version of libraries module it seems. There was a core change that changed how the cache backends are defined.

Update it, clear caches and it should work.

Comment: I'm using https://www.drupal.org/node/1775738 this version.  is there another version somewhere?

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> use Drupal\Core\Cache\CacheBackendInterface;
> ```
>
> What is the point of using an interface like that? Interfaces dont
> have actual code and this .module file doesnt inherit from that
> interface.

Interfaces are 'contracts' that any class implementing it must follow. An interface declares a number of functions. Any class that implements that interface must implement all the functions described in the interface, otherwise an error is thrown. Using interfaces as type hints, rather than using the actual class as a type hint, means that any class implementing the interface can be passed rather than just the original class, making your code more flexible.

For example, imagine three classes. Here are their declarations:

```
class Truck {
  ...
}

class Car implements CarInterface {
  ...
}

class Sedan extends Car {
  ...
}
```

Now let's look at a function that uses type hinting for arguments:

```
function doSomething(Car $vehicle) {
  ...
}
```

Now look at code that uses this function:

```
$car = new Truck();
doSomething($car);
```

This will force an error, as the `Truck` class does not implement `CarInterface`, and `doSomething()` requires an object that implements `CarInteface`. Next:

```
$car = new Car();
doSomething($car);
```

This will work, as `doSomething()` expects an object of type `Car`. The problem comes here:

```
$car = new Sedan();
doSomething($car);
```

This will thrown an error, as the `Sedan` class is not a `Car`, which `doSomething()` requires. Even though `Sedan` extends `Car`, and therefore has all the same properties and methods as `car`, and will therefore work as a replacement to `Car`, the code fails. This is not desirable, as you would have to write a new function to handle `Sedan`. It's also no good if your code is to be extensible by other developers that may not have the ability to contact you.

To get around this, instead of type hinting a class for the function, the interface is type hinted:

```
function doSomething(CarInterface $vehicle) {
  ...
}
```

Now that `doSomething()` expects a `CarInterface` rather than a `Car`, the following will work without errors:

```
$car = new Car();
doSomething($car);
$sedan = new Sedan();
doSometing($sedan);
```

This is because the `Sedan` class extends `Car`, and since `Car` implements `CarInterface`, so does `Sedan`. Now your code is extensible, because any developer can create a new class that either implements `CarInterface`, or extends `Car` (therefore implementing `CarInterface`), and use it with `doSomething()`, rather than only being able to pass a `Car` object.

To understand this a little deeper, take a look at a bit more code:

```
function doSomething(CarInterface $vehicle) {
  $doors = $vehicle->getNumberOfDoors();
}
```

This function calls the `getNumberOfDoors()` method on `$vehicle`. This means that if the object `$vehicle` does not have this method, an error will be thrown. To ensure that any value passed for `$vehicle` will have the method `getNumberOfDoors()`, this method is declared in the interface:

```
interface CarInterface {

  /**
   * Retrieves the number of doors on the car.
   *
   * @return int
   *   The number of doors on the car.
   */
  public function getNumberOfDoors(): int;
}
```

No code is declared in the interface, as this is only a contract, not the code definition. This contract requires that any class implementing `CarInterface` must have the method `getNumberOfDoors()`. If this method does not exist, a fatal error is thrown. So with this function:

```
function doSomething(CarInterface $vehicle) {
  $doors = $vehicle->getNumberOfDoors();
}
```

... we know that $vehicle will always have a `getNumberOfDoors()` method, as the `CarInterface` contract requires it. How that class implements this method is up to the class, as long as the return value is an integer